# How to drag and drop a Sprite in Sencha Touch Charts 2 Beta

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

I'm trying to understand the new beta release of Sencha Touch Charts 2. I'm not sure whether event handling is fully supported yet, but I need to drag Sprites around and generally get them to react to touch.

Has anyone tackled this yet? Any code snippets that would help?

Ext.util.Draggable does not feel like the right way to do it.

Update:

I now understand how the chart code handles the various chart interactions, and that interactions works in the new beta too. I've also noticed that the old Charts 1 code has little or no support for Sprite events either, and so the final example in the Draw Guide fails there too.

Maybe we are just meant to dip in to the chart code, learn, and then code our own stuff for non-chart Sprite events.

In charts 1, there's a draggable config item on Sprites. No idea how it's meant to work though. Looks like it may be a stubbed out feature.

Mike

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: No. I switched to D3.js for charting.